# items hidden by filters electron

Tags: node.js, angular, console, electron, chromium

I am creating an application in electron with angular2, where I make requests to an api. When disconnecting the machine from the internet, (because I want the application to work differently without internet) on the console, several errors are started with the title "items hidden by filters", as shown in the image.

This count increases very fast, only while the computer is not connected to the internet, when reconnecting the counter is paused.

I wonder if this is common in applications of this type, which use Chromium and Node.js. Can someone help me?

image: 
[items hidden by filters console erros](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXLC5.png)

Comment: It looks like your code is trying to read 'click' property from some object which is being set, if the application is connected with internet and it is null while disconnected. The browser is repeatedly checking this property and throwing the same error again and again.